# Link to related documents in another list

Tags: document-library, lookup-column, geolocation

I have two sharepoint lists.

- **List 1 has a list of projects and includes a geolocation column**. This allows me to view the projects on a map.
- **List 2 is a document library** where up to 3 documents are uploaded and associated to a project using a lookup column that points to list 1.

I want to be able to **easily access documents from a map view**. I see two ways to do this, but I can't figure out how to do either one.

**Option 1:** Somehow add links to the documents stored in list 2 to a view in list 1. Remember, there are up to 3 documents in list 2 for every project in list 1.

**Option 2:** Use a lookup column to add geolocation from List 1 to each document in List 2, related by the common `projectID`. The geolocation field does not show up as an option when using the standard lookup column.

Comment: When you display the projects on the map, can you try pulling the project's related docs from List 2 as well? You can achieve this using jsom if your map code is in javascript.